# Link to a User's Forum Profile From Their Comment

Tags: comments

How do I link a user's forum profile from their name in their comment. So far I've got this code in functions.php but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function force_comment_author_url($comment)
{
// does the comment have a valid author URL?
$no_url = !$comment->comment_author_url || $comment->comment_author_url == 'http://';

if ($comment->user_id && $no_url) {
// comment was written by a registered user but with no author URL
$comment->comment_author_url = 'http://www.examplesite.co.uk/forums/users/=' . $comment->username;
}
return $comment;
}
add_filter('get_comment', 'force_comment_author_url');
```

Please can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?